# Output append with input in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am creating a Calculator in C# windows form and after performing operation(+,-,*,/) the output of the operation append with the input of the next operation!

[This is the result of adding 33 in 33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZbEW.png)

[After pressing equal its gets 66 and when further input such as 33 is added input is appended to previous output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCNe9.png)

This is the code i have written so far..

```
    public Calculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (( txtResult.Text == "0")||(operation_pressed)) 
            txtResult.Clear();

        Button b = (Button)sender;                                              
        txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + b.Text;
        operation_pressed = false;

    }

    private void btnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if (b.Text == ".")
        {
            if (!txtResult.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + b.Text;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + b.Text;

        }
    }

    private void operator_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        operation = b.Text;

        value = Double.Parse(txtResult.Text);
        operation_pressed = true;

    }


    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtResult.Text = "0";
    }

    private void btnC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtResult.Clear();
        value = 0d;
    }

    private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (operation)
        {
            case "+":
                txtResult.Text = (value +  Double.Parse(txtResult.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "-":
                txtResult.Text = (value - Double.Parse(txtResult.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "*":
                txtResult.Text = (value * Double.Parse(txtResult.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "/":                
                txtResult.Text = (value / Double.Parse(txtResult.Text)).ToString();
                    break;

            default:
                break;

        } 
        operation_pressed = false;

        operation = "";
    }
```

Comment: Show us the codez. [mcve]

Comment: Most likely you're trying to perform arithmetic on a string, but that doesn't work since the `+` operator is a concatenation operator when used with strings. Show us your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't make us guess what you've done wrong! This post explains how to ask a question.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: StackOverflow, where a picture is definitely not worth a thousand words.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to field and don't know much about it, with experience i might be able to provide optimal information about problem being faced!!

Again Sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

The text is appending to the existing value because of this line in the `btn_click` event

```
txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + b.Text;
```

Earlier in this event, you are checking the value of `operation_pressed` before calling `txtResult.Clear();`, however you are setting this to false in the `btnEqual_Click` event.

Removing that line so that `operation_pressed` remains true after = is pressed would then clear the result on next button press.

On a side note, you will be better off storing the value in a variable, rather than parsing txtResult to double each time.

Comment: Removing operation_pressed after btnEqual event still gives the error